# Functions from Python packages for udf() of Spark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

For Spark dataframe via pyspark, we can use `pyspark.sql.functions.udf` to create a `user defined function (UDF)`.

I wonder if I can use any function from Python packages in `udf()`, e.g., `np.random.normal` from numpy?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you want to add a column named `new` to your DataFrame `df` constructed by calling `numpy.random.normal` repeatedly, you could do:

```
import numpy
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

udf = UserDefinedFunction(numpy.random.normal, DoubleType())

df_with_new_column = df.withColumn('new', udf())
```