# Is it possible to do a date-diff on a timestamp column with the current timestamp in Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to load a tab separated file containing two timestamp columns and generate a calculated column which is the difference (in days) between one of the columns and current timestamp. I have applied the registerTempTable() method on the RDD to convert it into a SchemaRDD. After that I have pretty much hit the wall as all subsequent operations depend on this datediff calculated field.

Here is what I have done so far. Thanks for the help !

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._


val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("CookieSummary")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD

case class CookieDates(CLPartnerSyncCreateDT: String, CookieSyncRequestDT: String)
val cookies = sc.textFile("/Users/shubhro/Documents/dataFiles/clean/worker1.01012015.1420081201_sub.tsv").map(_.split("\t")).map(p => CookieDates(p(0), p(1)))

cookies.registerTempTable("cookies")

val allCookies = sqlContext.sql("SELECT CAST(CLPartnerSyncCreateDT AS TIMESTAMP),CAST(CookieSyncRequestDT AS TIMESTAMP)  FROM cookies")

allCookies.collect().foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of spark are you using? I notice you use `SchemaRDD`, it's a notion that has been replaced in Spark 1.3.0 by `DataFrame`.

What you need here is to Define an `User Defined Function` and use it in `sql(...)`

In Spark 1.2.0:

```
val x = new TimeStamp(...) // The base time you want to diff
registerFunction("dateDiff", (arg: TimeStamp) => (arg - x))
sql("select dateDiff(col_name_here) from cookies")
```

After Spark 1.3.0: see [dataFrame notion on UDF usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909448/add-new-column-in-dataframe-base-on-existing-column/29912584#29912584)

Answer (score 2):

In Spark 1.5.0 a built-in function introduced:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8185