# scala - how to add a new column to Dataframe depending on the values of another one?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I've created a dataframe with info about sales. Now I want to add a column (`metric1`) with booleans to the dataframe which values will depend on the `sl.review` field: if `sl.review` contains an empty string, then `metric1` will be false and `true` otherwise if there is a review in `sl.review`.

```
val salesDf: DataFrame = salesRawDf.select($"stores", explode($"sales").as("sl"))
      .select($"stores.id", $"stores.name", $"sl.id", $"sl.current_sales", $"sl.review")
```

How is it possible to achieve with DataFrame? I've read this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909448/add-new-column-in-dataframe-base-on-existing-column) but still can't figure out how to implement this in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `when` function of spark like below

```
//Input df

+---+--------+-------+
|mid|   mname|mreview|
+---+--------+-------+
|100|     abc|       |
|101|     bcd|   Good|
|104|avengers|   Best|
|108|    Heri|       |
+---+--------+-------+

//Solution

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("metric1", when(df.col("mreview") === "", false) otherwise true).show

//Output df

+---+--------+-------+-------+
|mid|   mname|mreview|metric1|
+---+--------+-------+-------+
|100|     abc|       |  false|
|101|     bcd|   Good|   true|
|104|avengers|   Best|   true|
|108|    Heri|       |  false|
+---+--------+-------+-------+
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try using this User Defined Function which takes more than one single value as parameter:

```
def reviewIsEmpty = udf((review: String) => {
  review.isEmpty
})
```

And then just call it creating the new column:

```
import spark.implicits._
salesDf.withColumn("metric1", reviewIsEmpty($"sl.review"))
```

Of course, you can change the behavior of the UDF to check that the string is not only composed by blank spaces, for example.

Hope it helps